# The NOT LIKE clause is NOT working when executed by the sp_MSforeachdb function

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I execute the code below I'm STILL SEEING values in the ObjName column that begin with an 'x' value.  I cannot understand why.  I've also tried to use the following LIKE clause as well but to no avail:

AND o.name NOT LIKE ''x%''

Any help/direction on how to correct my issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.  Please see pic below as well showing one of my resultsets.

[image: NotLikeClauseIssue]

Here is my code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @text1 NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @text2 NVARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @text = 'DBSQLSERVER.' -- ENTER THE SQL SERVER BEING SEARCHED FOR.
SET @text1 = 'DBSQLSERVER].' -- ENTER THE SQL SERVER BEING SEARCHED FOR.
SET @text2 = 'x'                                                    --                                                                                                                                          |
SET @sql =                                                                          --                                                                                                                                          |
                                                                                                                    --                                                                                                                                          V           
                'USE [?]                                                                    
                SELECT ''?'' [DBName], @@SERVERNAME AS [WorkingServer], ''DBSQLSERVER'' AS [ServerToSearch], o.name AS [ObjName], o.type_desc [TypeDesc]
                FROM sys.sql_modules m 
                INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
                ON m.object_id = o.object_id
                WHERE m.definition LIKE ' + CHAR(39) + '%' + @text + '%' + CHAR(39) + '
                OR m.definition LIKE ' + CHAR(39) + '%' + @text1 + '%' + CHAR(39) + '
                AND o.name NOT LIKE '+ CHAR(39) + @text2 + '%' + CHAR(39) + '
                ORDER BY o.name asc'                
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql;
```

Comment: `OR` and `AND` have confusing precedence. Always add parentheses around entire clauses: `WHERE ((p) OR (q)) AND (s)` or you'll get nasty surprises like this.

Comment: Thanks so much Jeroen.  I appreciate the quick response.  That got it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ''?'' [DBName], @@SERVERNAME AS [WorkingServer], ''DBSQLSERVER'' AS [ServerToSearch], o.name AS [ObjName], o.type_desc [TypeDesc]
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
       ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.name NOT LIKE ' + CHAR(39) + @text2 + '%' + CHAR(39) + ' 
  AND (    m.definition LIKE ' + CHAR(39) + '%' + @text  + '%' + CHAR(39) + '
        OR m.definition LIKE ' + CHAR(39) + '%' + @text1 + '%' + CHAR(39) + '
      ) 
ORDER BY o.name asc'
```